# Sending data from HTML to node Js with Ajax

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ajax

I have an HTML page and would like to send an array so called output_list to Nodejs server. Html and Js file and Nodejs is running locally on may Macbook Pro.

**My code in HTML:**

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: {output_list: JSON.stringify(output_list)},
    success: function (res) {console.log("Output list transferred successfully") },
    error: function (err) { console.log("Transfer is not successful") },
});
```

**My code on Js file of NodeJs:**

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/Router36x36.html");
});

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    res.status(200).send(output_list.toString());
    res.send("Thanks for posting these");
});

app.listen(3000, function (req, res) {
    console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

**I have always get 405 error code.**

POST http://127.0.0.1:5500/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Router36x36.html:1114 Transfer is not successful.

If you help me to solve this problem I will be Appreciated.
Thanks
Adnan Sen

I have tried many things but could not find a way.

Comment: "Router36x36.html:1114 Transfer is not successful." — The URL to that file should be `/` so the browser shouldn't know about Router36x36.html. Odds are that you have loaded the HTML document from `file:///` instead of from `http://loalhost:3000/` by mistake.

Comment: `const bodyParser=require("body-parser");` — Express depends on body-parser and exposes it through https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded etc. There's no need to explicitly include body-parser.

Comment: Your server is listening port 3000 not 5500.

Comment: Could you write me the code for Nodejs side? I have changed my JQuery code like below.      $.ajax({
                        url: '/localhost:3000',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            json: JSON.stringify({cikis_listesi})
                        },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (res) { console.log("Output list transfered     successfully") },
                        error: function (err) { console.log("Transfer is not succesfull") }

                    });